# Can I delete my old saves to get Abyssal Armor at the start?

Tags: darksiders

I understand that if I want to be able to select the Abyssal Armour from the start I need to complete the game "On the First Run."

Having played through the game already, does this mean there is *no way* to get this, or do I simply have to delete my save game and play through again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wiki page seems to imply that you just need to collect the pieces before beating the game. It does not say anything about it needing to be your 'first time beating the game'.

http://darksidersdungeon.net/wiki/Abyssal_Armor

> When playing through Darksiders, **if you collect all ten pieces of the abyssal armor and then beat the game**, you can start a new record and you'll have the abyssal armor from the beginning. When going through the game at this point, each of the abyssal armor treasure chests will now contain 500 souls each.

(emphasis mine)